# sudoers audit error on kali linux

Tags: sudo, kali-linux, root

I update my kali linux successfully but on reboot when I use sudo command it did not work and got the following error:-
1)  error initializing audit plugin sudoers_audit

Comment: Please show us what `sudo` command you used, and the full set of error messages. Put these in your question, not in comments

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by updating the /etc/hosts file with the host information.

Example

```
127.0.0.1       host1 host1.mydomain.com  kali    localhost
```

Comment: How exectly did you update it? What was the error in it?

Comment: added the hostname to the first line (localhost line). There was no error in it, sudo was trying to do a host lookup and it seems as it failed (and "crashed" as a result of this failure) as this host was not in any dns. A big problem is that you can only do this as root (su command or in rescue mode or login as root through ssh if it's possbile).

Comment: Agree, that solved the problem for me as well.
But I couldn't figure out, which change caused this to suddenly raise a hard error. It used to just warn you.

Comment: yupp saw same thing as well. something must have changed in sudo /sudoers(i'm giessing) but have not verified